# Configure `.gitlab-ci.yml` for dependency scanning

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am currently trying to set up the native Gitlab SAST security scanning as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/). When I include the code that is specified on the website:

```
include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
```

I receive the following error in my CI:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.16
$ python -m venv .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
$ make -B venv
/bin/sh: eval: line 152: make: not found
Uploading artifacts for failed job
```

This is surprising to me because my CI setup file specifies a 3.11 Python image. It thus, seems to me that the security check is run in its own Docker container. How can I change this, such that the scan runs?

I tried to use the Gitlab template, but it did not work. Then I checked the docs for potential reasons, but I could not really spot any.